# How can I remove "None" in myresult

Tags: python

How can I delete "None" in the middle of output?

code:

```
class Car_store: # The name of a class must be a capital letter
    car_sold_counter = 0
    def __init__(self,name_of_car_be_sold):
        self.name_of_car_sold = name_of_car_be_sold # It shows which car was sold
        Car_store.car_sold_counter = Car_store.car_sold_counter + 1 # It counts the amount of cars sold
    def result(self):
        print('The name of the car sold: ',self.name_of_car_sold) # It will show the name of the car sold

Tesla = Car_store('Tesla') # It shows of a car name that's going to be sold

print(Tesla.result()) # It calls a function of "result"
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
#
# Here I have a problem with "None" , how can I remove it?
#
print('Number of cars sold: ',Car_store.car_sold_counter)
```

A result I want to get from output:

```
The name of the car sold:  Tesla
Number of cars sold:  1
```

Output:

```
The name of the car sold:  Tesla
None
Number of cars sold:  1
```

Comment: What is the type of `output` (e.g., string, array of strings, etc)?

Comment: I changed it, basically I have to get access to a function that prints it "result"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`print(f'{Tesla.result()}')` will print the `None`, because it prints the return value of `result()`.

Try:

```
class Car_store: # The name of a class must be a capital letter
    car_sold_counter = 0
    def __init__(self,name_of_car_be_sold):
        self.name_of_car_sold = name_of_car_be_sold # It shows which car was sold
        Car_store.car_sold_counter = Car_store.car_sold_counter + 1 # It counts the amount of cars sold
    def result(self):
        print('The name of the car sold: ',self.name_of_car_sold) # It will show the name of the car sold

Tesla = Car_store('Tesla') # It shows of a car name that's going to be sold

Tesla.result()
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
#
# Here I have a problem with "None" , how can I remove it?
#
print('Number of cars sold: ',Car_store.car_sold_counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your Car_store.result() function is doing 2 things:

1. Calling print()
2. Implicitly returning None

Then, your f-string is printing the None. You may want to change the result() function to something like this:

```py
    def result(self):
        return ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You use the `print()` twice by calling `print(Tesla.result())`.

"The name of the car sold:  Tesla" comes from `Tesla.result()`
"None" comes from the outer `print()` since `Tesla.result()` is void and returns None

Solution: change `print(Tesla.result())` to `Tesla.result()`

Answer (score 0):

This might solve the issue:

```
class Car_store: # The name of a class must be a capital letter
    car_sold_counter = 0
    def __init__(self,name_of_car_be_sold):
        self.name_of_car_sold = name_of_car_be_sold # It shows which car was sold
        Car_store.car_sold_counter = Car_store.car_sold_counter + 1 # It counts the amount of cars sold
    def result(self):
        return ('The name of the car sold: {name}'.format(name=self.name_of_car_sold)) # It will show the name of the car sold

Tesla = Car_store('Tesla') # It shows of a car name that's going to be sold

print(f'{Tesla.result()}')

#
# Here I have a problem with "None" , how can I remove it?
#
print('Number of cars sold: ',Car_store.car_sold_counter)
```

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to write a function is to make it return the result, and not print it inside the function code directy. So here is the modified result function, and way to call and display it.

```
class Car_store: # The name of a class must be a capital letter
    car_sold_counter = 0
    def __init__(self,name_of_car_be_sold):
        self.name_of_car_sold = name_of_car_be_sold # It shows which car was sold
        Car_store.car_sold_counter = Car_store.car_sold_counter + 1 # It counts the amount of cars sold
    def result(self):
        return self.name_of_car_sold

Tesla = Car_store('Tesla') # It shows of a car name that's going to be sold

print('The name of the car sold: ', Tesla.result())
""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
#
# No more problem with None being the return value of the function
#
print('Number of cars sold: ',Car_store.car_sold_counter)
```

Output is:

```
The name of the car sold:  Tesla
Number of cars sold:  1
```

Answer (score 0):

The `None` comes from Line 11 in this Example

```
print(Tesla.result())
```

The Function you call retorns nothing, so it printes `None`. And the Function printes the wanted output. to solve this change the function so that it doesn't print the solution but returns it. Maybe like this:

```
    def result(self):
        return 'The name of the car sold: ',self.name_of_car_sold
```

Or you can delete the print-Statement around the functioncall in line 11.